# Spring ImapMailReciever fetching all emails even after setting SearchTermStrategy

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I have configured ImapMailReciever and setSearchTermStrategy for it. I am trying fetch all emails from inbox using specific criteria- ReceivedDate Range and exclude emails from a specific domain. The AddressSearchTerm returns false if a message has matching address domain and hence should exclude that message being fetched itself. Below is the code snippet for same-

```
public class CustomSearchTermStrategy implements SearchTermStrategy {

    public SearchTerm generateSearchTerm(Flags flags, Folder folder) {
        SearchTerm olderThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LT, new Date("01-Aug-2020"));
        SearchTerm newerThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, new Date("05-Aug-2020"));
        
        SearchTerm term = new AddressSearchTerm("abc.com");
        SearchTerm [] termArray = new SearchTerm[]{olderThan, newerThan, term};
        return new AndTerm(termArray);    
    }
    
    private class AddressSearchTerm extends AddressStringTerm {
        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param pattern the address pattern to be compared.
         */
        protected AddressSearchTerm(String pattern) {
            super(pattern);
        }

        public boolean match(Message mesg){
            try {
                Address from[] = mesg.getFrom();
                for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
                    if (match(from[i])){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I run the application I see that IMAP starts fetching all emails and then excludes the emails from domain abc.com. Below are the IMAP debug logs-

A5 FETCH 1 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE)

- 1 FETCH (ENVELOPE ("email details" RFC822.SIZE 123)
  A5 OK FETCH completed.

Whereas, when I set the below SearchTermStrategy without AddressSearchTerm. IMAP does search uids first and then fetches only emails falling within the search criteria, which is the expected way of search -

```
public SearchTerm generateSearchTerm(Flags flags, Folder folder) {
    SearchTerm olderThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LT, new Date("01-Aug-2020"));
    SearchTerm newerThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, new Date("05-Aug-2020"));

    //SearchTerm term = new AddressSearchTerm(domain);
    SearchTerm [] termArray = new SearchTerm[]{olderThan, newerThan};
    return new AndTerm(termArray);
}
```

Below are the IMAP debug logs for above criteria-
A5 SEARCH BEFORE 5-Aug-2020 NOT ON 1-Aug-2020 SINCE 1-Aug-2020 ALL

- SEARCH 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 .....
  A5 OK SEARCH completed.

I have also tried using FromStringTerm to filter emails but that too doesn't work as expected.

The inbox has hundred thousands of emails hence I want to search the emails first and then fetch. How do I set correct search criteria for this, where am I going wrong?

Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: This is more Java Mail question than Spring Integration. The search feature is out of Spring Integration scope. It looks like you try to match against `from`. Consider to use a `FromStringTerm`  instead of your custom one.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan. I have already tried using FromStringTerm but that too isnt working as expected. I will edit and tag this question under javamail.